# Can (or should) a script perform a login?

Tags: scripts, login, encryption, sftp

I have a nightly process that SFTPs files from a Windows server to our Ubuntu server (12.04.5 LTS) using my username and login. A script is setup via cron (`sudo crontab -e`) runs later to copy those files, which are located in my encrypted directory, to an application directory. The script runs, but even using "sudo *commands*" the files **never get copied**.

Of course if I'm logged in then I can reschedule the script for testing and it will run perfectly. I really need to script to run without me being logged in. Is there any way to have the script log in, then log out before it completes, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There may be some extra details required. Do both directories belong to your user? If so - does your script really need to use sudo? Or is it running something that has to run as other user(root?) and be copied from root's directory? Also - it would help if you found out why exactly your cron script fails, otherwise it's just guessing. Another hint however may be to set the necessary commands allowed by sudo with nopasswd. Maybe not the greatest idea from security perspective, but sometimes unfortunately required.

Comment: Another option is, if you really need to login interactively, to use some extra tools, like expect, writing some wrapping script to handle the login. Expect for that will be relatively easy to learn at this level.

Answer (score 0):

So the script copying from the windows server to your ubuntu server's **encrypted home** (with eCryptfs right?) works OK, while you're logged in I'm assuming.

Then later when you're **not** logged in, another script can not access your encrypted home. That's by design, nothing is supposed to be able to access your encrypted home unless you're logged in.

You could modify the script to automatically log you in, but that most likely would break the security.

Or, you could have the second script run while you're still logged in.